# Check if data pandas.series value contains numeric character

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to check if a pandas series value contains *any* numeric characters and replace those who does not contain any with NaN?
`Series.str.isnumeric` only checks whether all characters are numeric.

Given the following series:

```
d = {'a': "Python", 'b': "$|", 'c': "|32", "c":"dos"}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c', "c"])
```

The only values that contain numeric characters are c, so that the values of a and b should be replaced with NaN. I am struggling to find a solution for this problem as there are multiple values for c which is therefore a pd.series by itself, according to `type(ser["c"])`

Comment: You cannot have multiple repeated keys in a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) + [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
res = ser.apply(lambda x: x if any(c.isnumeric() for c in x) else pd.NA)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
a    <NA>
b    <NA>
c     |32
c     |32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.contains('\d')` to check for existence of a digit. Then `groupby().transform('any')` to propagate that to the whole group. Finally, use `where` to mask the values of the series:

```
ser.where(ser.str.contains('\d').groupby(level=0).transform('any'))
```

Output:

```
a    NaN
b    NaN
c    |32
c    dos
dtype: object
```